# Checking missing hours for every id in a table

Tags: postgresql

I have a table that contains column  for id-s (`id_code`) and a time for transaction (`time`). What I need is to figure out those hours between two dates for each id where no transaction took place. Lets say i need to check missing hours for id 1 and id 2 from a table below `between 2014-06-13 12:00:00 and 2014-06-13 14:59:59` - the desired result would be that id 1 has missing transactions 2014-06-13 13:00:00 and id 2 is missing transactions 2014-06-13 14:00:00.

```
id_code  |  time    
1        |  2014-06-13 12:23:12    
2        |  2014-06-13 12:27:23    
1        |  2014-06-13 12:56:21    
2        |  2014-06-13 13:34:12    
1        |  2014-06-13 14:23:56
```

I am using **PostgreSQL 9.3**

Comment: show your sample output.

Comment: I would like the output to have a column for id-s and a column for hours that are missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/3db19/1)

```
select c.id, d.time
from
    (
        select distinct id
        from t
    ) c
    cross join
    generate_series (
        (select date_trunc('hour', min(t.time)) from t),
        (select date_trunc('hour', max(t.time)) from t),
        interval '1 hour'
    ) d(time)
    left join
    (
        select id, date_trunc('hour', t.time) as time
        from t
        group by id, 2
    ) t on t.time = d.time and c.id = t.id
where t.time is null
order by c.id, d.time
```

The `generate_series` will build a set of all possible hours. The cross join will make that a matrix of all possible ids of all possible hours. Then the `t.time is null` condition will filter those id x hours that do not exist.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT DISTINCT id, h FROM t, generate_series('2014-06-13 12:00:00'::timestamp, '2014-06-13 14:59:59'::timestamp, '1 hour') h
EXCEPT
SELECT id, date_trunc('hour', time) FROM t
```

Thanks to Clodoaldo Neto for providing a useful SQL Fiddle page for testing!

Comment: I like the elegance of `except`. Semantically your solution is more expensive since it first do the `cross join` and then the `distinct`. In practice it is possible that the planner figures out that it is cheaper to do the `distinct` first. Only testing will show.